# Eigen values of L2 projection Matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If I have an arbitrary set of $L^2$ functions $\{\phi_i\}$, then want to find the projection onto the subspace of $L^2$ generated by the basis, i.e $span\{\phi_i\}$, I believe I just need to solve

$A\alpha=\beta$

Where $A_{i,j}=\left\langle \phi_i,\phi_j\right\rangle_{L^2}$, $\beta_i=\left\langle \phi_i, f\right\rangle$, and then

$f_p=\sum_{i} \alpha_i \phi_i$

What I want to know, is how can I estimate the eigenvalues of $A$.

Clearly this has some similarity to a finite element analysis of the laplacian, but I don't want to restrict myself to the standard hat functions. The functions I'm using are still reasonably nice, so any results would be appreciated.